# How to transpose multiple columns values into one column based off of two indexes in Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

I am working with some family data which holds records on caregivers and the number of children that caregiver has. Currently, demographic information for the caregiver and all children that caregiver has is in the caregiver record. I want to take children's demographic information and put it into the the children's respective record/row. Here is an example of the data I am working with:

```
Vis POS FAMID   G1ID    G2ID    G1B   G2B1  G2B2  G2B3  G1R   G2R1   G2R2  G2R3                                                                  
1   0   1       100011          1979  2010              White White      
1   1   1               200011                                                   
1   0   2       100021          1969  2011  2009        AA    AA     White                                                                       
1   1   2               200021                                                   
1   2   2               200022                                                   
1   0   3       100031          1966  2008  2010  2011  White White   AA    AA                                                       
1   1   3               200031                                                              
1   2   3               200032                                                           
1   3   3               200033
```

G1 = caregiver data

G2 = child data

GxBx = birthyear

GxRx = race

## OUTPUT

```
Visit   POS FAMID   G1      G2      G1Birth     G2Birth     G1Race  G2Race
1       0   1       100011          1979                    White   
1       1   1               200011              2010                White
1       0   2       100021          1969                    AA  
1       1   2               200021              2011                AA
1       2   2               200022              2009                White
1       0   3       100031          1966                    White   
1       1   3               200031              2008                White
1       2   3               200032              2010                AA
1       3   3               200033              2011                AA
```

From these two tables you can see I want all G2Bx columns to fall into a new G2Birth column, and same principle for G2Rx columns. (I actually have several more instances like race and birthyear in my actual data)

I have been looking into pivots and stacking functions in the pandas dataframe but I hvaen't quite got what I wanted. The closest I have gotten was using the melt function, but the issue I have with the melt function was I couldn't get it to map to indexes with out taking all values from that column. IE it wants to create a row for child2 and child3 for people who only have child1. I might just be using the melt function incorrectly.

What I want are all values from g2Birthdate1 to map onto POS when POS=1, and all g2Birthdate2 to the POS=2 index, etc. Is there a function which can help accomplish this? Or does this require a some additional coding solution?

Comment: Look at using a very fun pandas function `pd.wide_to_long`.  It is a bit tricky to use.

Comment: @ScottBoston Thanks, I'm taking a look now. The issue I found with a lot of these shaping functions are they can't transpose data with out expanding or reducing the indexes. In my case I have the indexed spots open, but I just want to map my column data onto those open spaces.

Comment: Actually, @Alex. `pd.wide_to_long` probably will not solve your problem.  I actually tried a solution that did work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a row and a column MultiIndex and a left join:

```
# df is your initial dataframe

# Make a baseline dataframe to hold the IDs
id_df = df.drop(columns=[c for c in df.columns if c not in ["G1ID", "G2ID","Vis","FAMID","POS"]])

# Make a rows MultiIndex to join on at the end
id_df = id_df.set_index(["Vis","FAMID","POS"])

# Rename the columns to reflect the hierarchical nature 
data_df = df.drop(columns=[c for c in df.columns if c in ["G1ID", "G2ID", "POS"]])

# Make the first two parts of the MultiIndex required for the join at the end
data_df = data_df.set_index(["Vis","FAMID"])

# Make the columns also have a MultiIndex
data_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("G1Birth",0),("G2Birth",1),("G2Birth",2),("G2Birth",3),
                                             ("G1Race",0),("G2Race",1),("G2Race",2),("G2Race",3)])

# Name the columnar index levels
data_df.columns.names = (None, "POS")

# Stack the newly formed lower-level into the rows MultiIndex to complete it in prep for joining
data_df = data_df.stack("POS")

# Join to the id dataframe on the full MultiIndex
final = id_df.join(data_df)
final = final.reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't gotten a chance to try this yet, but when I can I will respond back.

Comment: This ended up getting me close to where I wanted. Thanks for the help.